# Is it legal to copy the design of a website only to demonstrate coding ability to clients, nothing more?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

I'm trying to find out what is "fair use" or not. I'm a web developer trying to get off the ground and my website portfolio has nothing. So, I'm thinking to have a section of my website called "how-to recreations" or the like, where I link to websites that I've programmed from scratch that are modeled after existing, possibly copyrighted websites. I would make my source code (for the design and not the server/database functionality; for the HTML/CSS/JavaScript, if you're tech-savvy) open-source, I wouldn't sell the recreation as a template, and on the page on my portfolio website<sup>**1**</sup> that links to this recreation, I would state and link back to the site that I recreated and explain how I coded various elements of that site. It would just be used to show my coding ability to potential clients and to teach other programmers one way that a site's design out there could be implemented with code.

**Tl;dr** I'm copying a site's design solely for demonstrative/instructional purposes. Is that legal?

<sup>**1**</sup>I'm thinking to not make this page anything other than a how-to and a link to the recreation. But, if I wanted to, could I link back to my portfolio for potential clients that want to hire me based on this how-to/recreation? Would everything still be "fair use"?

Comment: Just because you make a design similar to site X does not mean you are copying it. For example Google's start page has a logo and a line where you type a query. So does Duckduckgo. It doesn't mean Duckduckgo actually *copied* Google's page or 'design'. Maybe they were inspired by it though.

Answer (score -2):

If you copy a copyrighted image, yes that is illegal.

You can just make mock logos and graphics and place the logo at the top with navigation and such. Most websites follow the same similar formula in that regard, so you don't need to copy anything.

Comment: All images, graphics, and icons would be either original or royalty-free. The content would be filler text. But the color scheme (not exactly, as do everything by eye), the layout, the elements, the general design of things, and functionality would be the same.

Comment: I get that, but you still can't knock off a recognizable logo or whatever.

Comment: You can just make a completely different logo put it on the top of the page and then make a background or whatever. You don't even need to copy.

Comment: Right, I'm not concerned about copying the logo. This would be the logo I use for a coffee shop website recreation, for example: https://i.ibb.co/q1CC7SS/Screen-Shot-2019-12-03-at-12-38-32.png

Comment: You aren't really copying anything then.

Comment: Well, there is website copyright, in addition to code copyright. I can't steal the design of facebook.com just like I can't steal the code for it. But you're saying that I can make a website using a similar blue color scheme to facebook.com, using the same elements and arrangement of them, and so forth, AKA copying the design, all coded from scratch and all graphics/images/content/icons original or royalty-free, solely for the purpose of demonstrating my coding ability and teaching programmers?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by similar. Obviously Starbucks.com and whatever coffee shop.com are going to be similar in that they have the logo at the top, some sorta images of coffee and a nav bar at the top. That is fine because they are clearly not copying one another, it just makes sense to put a logo and nav bar at the top and have coffee images below. If you do copy the look of Facebook, but call it Romanbook, that is not ok.

Comment: I'm doing neither. I'm copying a website exactly, but not calling it anything or using it. In fact, I'm calling it "recreation of x website." The only way people will find this recreation is through my how-to page explaining that it's modeled after x website and how I did it, nothing more. So, imagine starbucks.com exactly but with a fake logo, different images, "lorem ipsum" text, and free fonts and icons. Just for the purpose of showing how starbucks.com could be built. I don't see what the problem is. I'm not making an actual coffee shop site after starbucks.com or selling it as a template.

Comment: Just say example of a coffee place site and leave it at that.

Comment: Ok. I'll change the "recreation of x website" to "coffee shop example site" and I won't mention the name of the original anywhere in the how-to. Why can't I specify who it's an example of?

Comment: BC you are copying their works then.